# How to control in-memory generated key values in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core, integration-testing, in-memory-database

### Background

I am developing a Web application based on ASP.NET Core 2.1 and EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.1. Besides other type of tests, I am using [InMemory Web API testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) to have some kind of integration testing of the Web.Api.

Since test data is rather convoluted I have generated a JSON file based on a slice of a migrated database and testing is importing data from this JSON file when the in-memory tests kick in.

### The issue

Read-only tests are working just fine. However, when I insert something for an entity that has an identity (`ValueGenerated == ValueGenerated.OnAdd`) it automatically gets a value of 1 (all PKs are `int`s). This makes sense since whatever generator EF is using behind the scene to generate those values was not instructed to generate from a certain value.

**However, this is clearly not working properly for inserts that generate an existing key value.**

### Things I have tried

1. [current working solution] **Shifting the key values** - Upon deserializing all objects, I perform an ids shift operations for all involved entities (they get "large" values). This works properly, but it is error prone (e.g. some entities have static ids, I have to ensure that all foreign keys / navigations properties are properly defined and it is kind of slow right now since I rely on reflection to properly identity the keys / navigation properties that require shifting)
2. [Configuring value generator to start from a large value](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6872#issuecomment-258025241):

#### TestStartUp.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IValueGeneratorCache, ValueGeneratorCache>();
services.AddSingleton<ValueGeneratorCacheDependencies, ValueGeneratorCacheDependencies>();
```

#### Ids generation functionality

```
public const int StartValue = 100000000;

class ResettableValueGenerator : ValueGenerator<int>
{
    private int _current;

    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

    public override int Next(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref _current);
    }

    public void Reset() => _current = StartValue;
}


public static void ResetValueGenerators(CustomApiContext context, IValueGeneratorCache cache, int startValue = StartValue)
{
    var allKeyProps = context.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        .Select(e => e.FindPrimaryKey().Properties[0])
        .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(int));
    var keyProps = allKeyProps.Where(p => p.ValueGenerated == ValueGenerated.OnAdd);

    foreach (var keyProperty in keyProps)
    {
        var generator = (ResettableValueGenerator)cache.GetOrAdd(
            keyProperty,
            keyProperty.DeclaringEntityType,
            (p, e) => new ResettableValueGenerator());

        generator.Reset();
    }
}
```

When debugging I can see that my entities being iterated, so the reset is applied.

#### Pushing the data into the in-memory database

```
private void InitializeSeeding(IServiceScope scope)
{
    using (scope)
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        try
        {
            var context = services.GetRequiredService<CustomApiContext>();

            // this pushes deserialized data + static data into the database
            InitDbContext(context);

            var valueGeneratorService = services.GetRequiredService<IValueGeneratorCache>();
            ResetValueGenerators(context, valueGeneratorService);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = services.GetService<ILogger<Startup>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Actual insert

This is done using a generic repository, but boils down to this:

```
Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

**Question:** How to control in-memory generated key values in Entity Framework Core?

Comment: So, the entities in your JSON are inserted with whatever Ids they have. What's not working is when you insert new data, they don't start with the new value (100000000)?

Comment: @jpgrassi - yes, JSON is actually a serialization of production like data which have "small" keys (<10M). Whatever is inserted using in-memory provider starts with 1.